# ElasticSearch - exclude special character from standard stemmer

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using standard analyzer for my ElasticSearch index, and I have noticed that when I search a query with `%` in it - the analyzer drops the `%` as part of the stemmer steps (on the query "2% milk")

```
GET index_name/_analyze 
{
  "field": "text.english",
  "text": "2% milk"
}
```

The response is the following 2 tokens (`2` and `milk`):

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "2",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 1,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "milk",
      "start_offset": 3,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Meaning, the `2%` becomes `2`

I want to use the standard stemmer to reduce punctuation, I don't want to use the space stemmer or other stemmer which is not standard but I do want to use the `<number>%` sign as term in the index.

Is there a way to configure to the stemmer to ignore special character when it's next to a number? worst case not to ignore it at all?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? To me it's not clear what you want to achieve. By default Elasticsearch "ignores" the %-character, "leaving" only term "2". Do you want Elasticsearch to ignore the whole expression (e.g. "2%"), so not producing any token for it, or do you want to preserve it as a single token including the percentage character?

Comment: I want ElasticSearch to preserve it as single token include the percentage. When I search for "2% milk" I don't want to get results for "2 milk"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the desired behavior by configuring a custom analyzer using a character filter that preserves the "%"-character from getting stripped away.

Check the Elasticsearch documentation about the configuration of the built-in analyzers, to use that configuration as a blueprint to configure your custom analyzer (see Elasticsearch Reference: [english analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer))

Add a character filter that maps the percentage-character to a different string, as demonstrated in the following code snippet:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "my_percent_char_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_percent_char_filter": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "0% => 0_percent",
            "1% => 1_percent",
            "2% => 2_percent",
            "3% => 3_percent",
            "4% => 4_percent",
            "5% => 5_percent",
            "6% => 6_percent",
            "7% => 7_percent",
            "8% => 8_percent",
            "9% => 9_percent"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST my_index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "The fee is between 0.93% or 2%"
}
```

With this, you can even search for specific percentages (like `2%`)!

**Alternative Solution**

If you simply want to remove the percentage character, you can use the very same approach, but simply map the `%`-character to an empty string, as shown in the following code snippet

```
"char_filter": {
  "my_percent_char_removal_filter": {
    "type": "mapping",
    "mappings": [
      "% => "]
  }
}
```

BTW: This approach is not considered to be a "hack", it's the standard solution approach to modify your original string before it gets sent to the tokenizer.

Comment: I can generate it to use ```"char_filter": {
      "char_percent_replacer": {
        "type": "pattern_replace",
        "pattern": "(\\d+)%",
        "replacement": "$1_percent"
      }
    } ``` However I wanted to understand if there is a way to exclude this character from ES analyzer, and not to hack it with a new term like _percent

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood you. I though you had asked about "preserving" the percentage character as part of the token. You may want to check the updated response with an alternative, simpler solution that simply ignores (and removes) the %-character from your data and search query. BTW: this has nothing to do with stemming (which is simply about dealing with language specific word variations). It's a task either for a character or token filter as part of the analysis process. Hope that helped.